# Plane backface culling

Tags: objects, normals

I'm trying to get a plane without one face culled. I have tried to tick the "double sided" box in the object data, but it didn't work.
So i've tried to duplicate the plane, flip the normal and join the two planes, but surprisingly when in edit mode it was like the two planes were still separated, as i could rotate one plane and not the other.
The last choice is to solidify the plane, but i would like to find another solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: In which rendering engine are you trying to do this?

Comment: If it's unity,, it doesn't support double-sided faces. So the solidify is the only solution (the rims could be disabled).

Comment: it is unity, yes. Thanks for your answer!
Although it's still strange to me that joining a mesh will still cause edit mode to work on the planes as if they're separate objects